# Finding the MLE of $\theta$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

Working through this given problem on maximum likelihood estimation (MLE). The density is given as

$$f(x \mid \theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta} e^{-|x|/\theta}, -\infty < x <\infty $$

I get

$$L(\theta)= \frac{1}{(2\theta)^{n}} e^{- \frac{1}{2\theta} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|}$$

Applying the ln step

$$\ln L(\theta)= -n\ln(2\theta) - \frac{1}{\theta}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|$$

Taking the derivative

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} = \frac{-n}{\theta} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|}{\theta^{2}}$$

Setting the derivative to 0 and solving for $\theta$

$$\frac{-n}{\theta} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|}{\theta^{2}} = 0 $$
$$\hat{\theta}= \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|}{n}$$

Is this correct or have i done a something wrong and im getting the wrong mle

Comment: Looks good to me. What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: @stuartstevenson i just learn how to do it and i wanna make sure im understading it correctly

Comment: I think you're good. Exactly what I would expect to see from the question.